# Is there a way to retain the order of variables in a Spark Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm creating a Spark Dataset as

```
Dataset<myBeanClass> myDataset = myDataFrame.as(Encoders.bean(myBeanClass.class));
```

At this point, its schema looks like,

```
 root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
```

After performing a map transformation,

```
Dataset<myBeanClass> resultDataset = myDataset.map(new MapFunction<myBeanClass,myBeanClass>() {
    @Override
    public myBeanClass call(myBeanClass v1) throws Exception {

        // some code
        return v1;
    }

}, Encoders.bean(myBeanClass.class));
```

the schema becomes

```
 root
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Noticed the same behavior in [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets) example as well. Is there a way to retain the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to stop the order of variables in the schema from changing. But I was able to convert it back to whatever order I wanted. Here is how I did it,

```
DataFrame resultsDataFrame = myDataset.toDF().selectExpr(myDataFrame.schema().fieldNames());
```

The schema for resultsDataFrame is same as the schema of the DataFrame I created the Dataset from

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
```